# Sequelize model custom function cannot be called from controller

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model this custom functions like so:

```
'use strict';
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../../config');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
id: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  primaryKey: true
},
name: DataTypes.STRING,
email: DataTypes.STRING,
bio: DataTypes.STRING,
phone: DataTypes.STRING,
username: DataTypes.STRING,
password: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  set(value){
    this.setDataValue('password', bcrypt.hashSync(value, 10));
  }
}
}, {});

User.generateJWT = function(id, username) {
return jwt.sign({
  id: id,
  username: username,
  expiresIn: config.auth.exp
}, config.secret);
};

User.toAuthJson = async function() {
return {
  name: this.name,
  email: this.email,
  bio: this.bio,
  phone: this.phone,
  username: this.username
};
};

User.validatePassword = function(password, passwordHash){
return bcrypt.compareSync(password, passwordHash);
};

User.isUniqueEmail = async function(email) {
  return await User.findOne({where: {email}}) === null;
};

User.isUniqueUsername = async function(username) {
  return await User.findOne({where: {username}}) === null;
};

User.isUniquePhone = async function(phone) {
 return await User.findOne({where: {phone}}) === null;
};
User.associate = function(models) {
// associations can be defined here
};
return User;
};
```

and a controller like so:

```
const {User} = require('../database/models/');

module.exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
       const isUniqueEmail = await User.isUniqueEmail(req.body.email);
        if (!isUniqueEmail) return  res.status(422).json({'message': 'email already exists'});

        const isUniquePhone = await User.isUniquePhone(req.body.phone);
        if (!isUniquePhone) return  res.status(422).json({'message': 'phone already exists'});

        const isUniqueUsername = await User.isUniqueUsername(req.body.username);
        if (!isUniqueUsername) return  res.status(422).json({'message': 'username already exists'});

         const user = await User.create(req.body);
         console.log(user.toAuthJson()); //an error occurs here
        return res.status(201).json({user: user.toAuthJson()});
    }catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
 };
```

when i try to access the toAuthJson function from this controller like this user.toAuthJson. "notice the small u." it throws an error TypeError: User.toAuthJson is not a function. I should be able to access it normally. help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User.toAuthJson` is currently a class method. Like with the other functions, you'd need to call it like `User.toAuthJson(user)`.

You're probably looking for an instance method, so you'd want to define it in the prototype instead:

```
User.prototype.toAuthJson = function() {
  return {
    name: this.name,
    email: this.email,
    bio: this.bio,
    phone: this.phone,
    username: this.username
  };
};
```

Now you can call it on a `User` instance, like you were attempting to do:

```
console.log(user.toAuthJson());
```

Notice also that I omitted the `async` since this function doesn't do anything asynchronous.